# How can I make a webpage move with the movement of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that needs to contain an iframe that links to external content as well as a left navbar.  I would like to use only 1 scroll bar (the one from the eyeframe is preferred) to control both the iframe and the left navigation bar.  Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Not possible with "_external content_", for security reasons (Lookup _Same Origin policy_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
$("#iframeId").scroll(function () { 
  window.scroll($(this).scrollLeft(), $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

only works for content from same origin though